Generate _pb2 python files with grpcio-tools with Decimal google type
I need to send python Decimal with gRPC.
To do so i wrote this simplified proto file
syntax = "proto3";

package grpc.dec;

import "google/type/decimal.proto";

message Data {
  google.type.Decimal total = 1;
}

What i have installed into my venv
(venv) ➜ pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ -------
googleapis-common-protos 1.63.0
grpcio                   1.63.0
grpcio-tools             1.63.0
pip                      23.0.1
protobuf                 4.25.3
setuptools               58.1.0

So i have site-packages/google/type/decimal.proto with Decimal message
And grpcio-tools to run
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I./proto --python_out=./proto/  --grpc_python_out=./proto/ --mypy_out=./proto/ ./proto/*.proto

But what i got when run this command
google/type/decimal.proto: File not found.
dec.proto:5:1: Import "google/type/decimal.proto" was not found or had errors.
dec.proto:210:3: "google.type.Decimal" is not defined.

I tried different variants and chatGPT advices, but nothing works. Please explain me how it should work

To use google/type/decimal.proto, you need to ensure that its repro googleapis is accessible (using --proto_path) when you invoke protoc.
To do this:

Clone the repo (you can store this wherever you'd like)

GOOGLEAPIS="${PWD}"

git clone \
https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis \
${GOOGLEAPIS}


Rerun protoc referencing --proto_path=${GOOGLEAPIS}:

python \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
--proto_path=${GOOGLEAPIS} \
--proto_path=${PWD}/proto \
--python_out=${PWD}/proto \
--grpc_python_out=${PWD}/proto \
--mypy_out=${PWD}/proto \
${PWD}/proto/*.proto

The --proto_path (-I) flag provides protoc with a mechanism to find protocol buffer sources.
In your case, it looks in each --proto_path for a folder that contains the following tree:
.
└── google
    └── type
        └── decimal.proto

Because the import package is google/type/decimal.proto.
Which is the conventional way to reflect decimal.proto's package google.type (NB the . in the package are folders on the filesystem).
The googleapis repo includes this tree and thus it satsfies protoc.

Thanks! I copied decimal.proto to my proto directory, but though that i'm doing something wrong. It seems to be the legit way.

You can do that too but it could become problematic. decimal.proto is a 3rd-party (Google) source and should be kept distinct from your repo. Google may update decimal.proto (and you should too). Although unlikely, the source may evolve to include its own import's and then you'd have problems. Hopefully my explanation makes sense and provides you with a.... safer path forward.
